# windows based iphone SDK needed

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iphone SDK on Windows (alternative solutions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928656/iphone-sdk-on-windows-alternative-solutions)

Hello,

From where can i get windows SDK kit of iPhone development in free ? I am new on iPhone development and i want to start it.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Officially there is no Windows SDK. Apple wants development of apps for their platform done on their other platform.  There are some alternatives, but they can be  hit or miss depending on your needs.

This is discussed in length in this topic:
[iPhone SDK on Windows (alternative solutions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928656/iphone-sdk-on-windows-alternative-solutions)