# How can I run the iPhone development tools on Windows? Is it even possible?

Tags: iphone, windows, ios, macos, titanium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

Hello 
friends,

I Want To Know that   Is i-phone development  possible on the other operating system than 
Mac?
I  does know About titanium framework  is It  Good to  use 
If YEs 
    Can Anybody Suggest me The Reference link for that?

thank you Very Much In Advance

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928656/iphone-sdk-on-windows-alternative-solutions

Comment: No. Buy a Mac and an iPhone if you wish to develop for iPhone.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [iPhone development on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows), please search before posting new questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a compatible processor, you could run VMWare and run Mac OS X Snow Leopard Server in VMWare.

Comment: McRae:I Have Heard about the Airplay sdk  this can work for mac As well as window operating system  and this is for  game development  only

Comment: I just came across this thing called AirPlay SDK. It's supposedly cross platform iPhone/Symbian/Android game development that is free for iPhone, and 99$/year for other platforms (for indie developers, which means you make less than 50K us per year)

Comment: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/3221

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to use Mac OS X on a Mac to develop for iPhone.